# import QtQuick.Window 2.2 QML MODULE NOT FOUND

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I'm trying to use `design` in `qtcreator` with `QML` file but I'm getting an error while importing `QtQuick.Window`. My `QML` file starts like that:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import bluesat.owr 1.0
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Try to change `QtQuick.Window` version to lower.

Comment: What Qt version do you use?

Comment: @UgniusMalūkas I tried different version but the same issue.

Comment: @folibis Qt Creator 3.4.1 (opensource) Qt 5.4.2

Comment: I think you have that problem because probably for Qt 5.4 there was no such class, update your Qt, the LTS version is Qt 5.9, and the current version is Qt 5.10.1